# rails remove file for public folder

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, caching

I am trying to edit files in folder public but I don't know why whenever I make changes it is not showing.

I have created a file called test.html inside public folder. And I am calling it using javascript for that my code is :

```
  $("#click2").click(function(){
   console.log("click2");

  $('#content').load( 'test.html' );

   });
```

I am making changes to my test.html file but it is not showing even when I delete the file it still show the content of that.  I want to make changes and want to see what should I do .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The public folder should be used for storing never-changing assets, such as favicons or robots.txt files, as the results will be cached by browsers.

If you're set on doing this, try clearing your browser cache between changes.

Comment: I have done browser caching no luck it reflect after an hour